# count up + 1 in looping data in table

Tags: loops, vbscript, foreach, asp-classic

I have this loop that gives me data in the form of a table, but I haven't figured out how to loop + 1 into it so there will be a number on the left side of each row of data in order, like 1, 2, 3, 4. I am using MSSQL to get the data and the table works great in regards to that. Just want numbers at beginning of each row.

Here is my current code:

```
<%
if delivery_id<>"" Then 

for each x in rs.Fields
response.write"<th><b>" & (UCASE(x.name) & "</b></th>")
next%>
</tr>
<%do until rs.EOF%>
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields %>
  <td>  <% Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
<%next
rs.MoveNext%>
</tr>
<%loop
rs.close
conn.close
end if
%>
</table></font>
```

Can anyone assist me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with ASP, but normally just putting in a counter variable and incrementing it inside the loop should do what you want:

```
...
<%i = 0
Do Until rs.EOF
i = i + 1%>
<tr>
  <td><% Response.Write i %></td>
<%For Each x In rs.Fields %>
  <td>  <% Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
<%Next
rs.MoveNext%>
</tr>
<%Loop
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by setting your intC int.

**Dim IntC**

Assign a start value.

**IntC = 0**

Place the value inside your For Each statement.

Adding 1 within your *for each loop* statement.

**intC = intC + 1**

Place the results before your response.write in your

If you need to add a space use the `&nbsp;` between the

**<%=IntC%>. `&nbsp;`<%Response.Write.....**

Below is your sample code with the field count code in place.
Note: If you need to reset the counter when you start processing the *do until* simply zero the counter out above the <%loop by adding intC = 0

```
<%
Dim intC
intC = 0

if delivery_id<>"" Then 

for each x in rs.Fields
response.write"<th><b>" & (UCASE(x.name) & "</b></th>")
next%>
</tr>
<%do until rs.EOF%>
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields 
intC = intC + 1
%>
  <td><%=intC%>. <% Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
<%next
rs.MoveNext%>
</tr>
<%loop
rs.close
conn.close
end if
%>
</table></font>
```